# Can not start webhttrack

Tags: 12.04, package-management, google-chrome

I am trying to start my webhttrack on ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin but all i get is the
opening screen. When i press any button on the page it gives me the following
errors:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to barney:8081
Suggestions:
Try reloading: barney:Â­8081/Â­server/Â­step2.Â­html
```

i tried to run from a terminal window and get the output here:

```
webhttrack
/usr/bin/webhttrack(4405:( launching /usr/bin/x-www-browser
/usr/bin/webhttrack(4405:( spawning regular browser..
Created new window in existing browser session.
/usr/bin/webhttrack(4405:( browser exited
/usr/bin/webhttrack: line 167:  4422 Killed                 
${BINPATH}/htsserver "${DISTPATH}/" path "${HOME}/websites" lang "${LANGN}"
$@
```

If anyone can help me i appreciate it.

Comment: Try running `http://yourHostname:8080/server/index.html` in your browser.

Comment: Your hostname means run `hostname` in terminal , copy that name and replace that in yourhostname in above address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same bug.

It seems that after editing

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

and commenting all the lines like :

```
#Listen 8080
#NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

and :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

it works.

I don't have the time to play around and investigate the bug more than that

PS: Before that I also installed the last quantal version but it didn't change a thing

Comment: hum, bug again it seems the problem is with using chrome, using firefox is ok

Answer (score 7):

You can use firefox instead of chrome. Interestingly, you don't even need to **use** firefox as long as you **open** it. (Would be interested to know why this could be.) My default browser is chrome and webhtttrack won't open there unless firefox is open as well.

Comment: same here and your solution works great!!

Comment: this it truly funny.

Comment: amazing. open firefox and it starts working in chrome. I didn't expect this to work but it does.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was using chrome/chromium.

As described [here](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/25647/index.html), i hardcoded firefox in the webhttrack script:

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/webhttrack
```

and modified the first line into:

```
BROWSEREXE="firefox"
```

works like a charm after!

Comment: even after modified this line, it continues to open chrome :S. For me, the only way to get it work is to have both firefox and chrome opened.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it will still want to use Chrome or even another browser. I used this trick and it worked good for me.

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/webhttrack
```

Then there I search the line:

```
BROWSEREXE=
```

and change it to

```
BROWSEREXE="firefox"
```

Then I search for:

```
SRCHBROWSEREXE="x-www-browser www-browser iceape mozilla firefox icecat iceweasel abrowser firebird galeon konqueror opera chrome chromium chromium-browser netscape"
```

and just comment the line with `#`:

```
#SRCHBROWSEREXE="x-www-browser www-browser iceape mozilla firefox icecat iceweasel abrowser firebird galeon konqueror opera chrome chromium chromium-browser netscape"
```

Now just save and run, and it will open the browser of your choice.