# httrack is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, apache2, httrack

Recently I installed HTTrack  from software center with its required add-ons. But after installation. its not working. I can see an icon in application menu. And when I click on it. It takes me to browser and opens `http://mypcname:8080`. But it shows `web page not available`. What is the problem with it . I have installed apache in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 may require the program HTTraQt - graphical user interface (GUI) for HTTrack library.
I could not get httrack or webhttrack to work at all until after I installed HTTraQT from Synaptic.

Alternatively, run the following command:.

```
sudo apt-get install httraqt
```

in your terminal to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only way, but it got mine working.

For me the problem was using Google Chrome and I've heard, Chromium, too.

(Open in Terminal): You'll need to hardcode Mozilla Firefox in the WebHTTrack script:

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/webhttrack
```

Modify the first line into:

```
BROWSEREXE="firefox"
```

*Hope this helps! If not, reference this page: "([Can not start webhttrack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157613/can-not-start-webhttrack))".